# Calculate sales commission with maximum vlaue in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I am trying to calculate a sales commission with a maximum value of 25000 for the year. for example if an employee earning $3000 a month so the total for the year will be $36000. however I have to pay maximum $25000.
I tried window functions like sum(mtd_commission) over month and compare it against 25000 however it stops after 8th month or 24000. how I can calculate only (25000-24000) $1000 for the 9th month.

Thanks

[expected results]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below query.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT month, 3000 mtd_comm FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 12)) month
)
SELECT *,
       SUM(mtd_comm) OVER w0 ytd_comm,
       CASE 
         WHEN SUM(mtd_comm) OVER w0 <= 25000 THEN mtd_comm
         ELSE GREATEST(0, 25000 - SUM(mtd_comm) OVER w1)
       END AS paid_comm,
       LEAST(25000, SUM(mtd_comm) OVER w0) ytd_paid_comm,
  FROM sample_table
WINDOW w0 AS (ORDER BY month),
       w1 AS (ORDER BY month RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
;
```

**Query results**

[image]